# search string through array

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String a[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
String str = "d";


for (int i = 0; i < a[i].length(); i++) 
{
    if (str.equals(a[i])) 
    {
        System.out.println("Found number" + " " + str);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not found");
        break;
    }
}
```

did not getting output

Comment: `a[i].length()` is `1` in your example (the length of an individual string), did you mean `a.length` (the length of the array = 4)?

Comment: also you may want to wait with determining that nothing was found until the whole loop completes

Comment: and always `break`ing at the first iteration makes the loop kinda pointless

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using the length of a string element in the array, not the array itself.  To print only one message, assign a default message and then change it when the string is found.  Only break when found to ensure you check all the strings.

```
String a[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
String str = "d";
String message = "Not found.";

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (str.equals(a[i])) { 
        message = "Found letter: " + str;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should break or return when the target string if found.

once the loop is completed, add a print statement outside of the loop stating the target string is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to use length() method which is used to get length or size of any string object and not for string arrays, incase if you wanted to check size of any string you could have used `length()`,but since you are working with arrays you have to use `length`.
Below snippet is updated and I have removed `length()` with length to travese over array elements and removed `break` statement as break statement exit the current loop and goes to the next statement for execution

```
String a[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" }; 
String str = "d";
        
          for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            {
                if (str.equals(a[i])) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Found number" + " " + str);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Not found");
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Not found
Not found
Found number c
Not found              it prints both if else condition together . I want only one condition at a time

Comment: As you have added print statement for `If` and `Else` it will print the statement whenever it matches the condition and in this case since it doesnt match 3 times it is going to `Else` block and printing the statement within else block. If you want to print only once then use one global variable and store the statement and print it at the end after for loop completes